# toggle 2 checkboxes between two rows over multiple columns

Tags: jquery

I have to up 15 columns in a table and 2 rows of checkboxes.  The user can select either 'surface' or 'flush' for all columns.

```
 <tr class="MESurfaceMountRow">
     <td>Surface Mount</td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name="" id="MESurfaceMount1"></td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name="" id="MESurfaceMount2"></td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name="" id="MESurfaceMount3"></td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name="" id="MESurfaceMount4"></td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name="" id="MESurfaceMount5"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="MEFlushMountRow">
      <td>Flush Mount</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name="" id="MEFlushMount1"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name="" id="MEFlushMount2"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name="" id="MEFlushMount3"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name="" id="MEFlushMount4"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="" name="" id="MEFlushMount5"></td>
 </tr>
```

I understand how to toggle between 'MESurfaceMount1' and 'MEFlushMount1' using jquery for example.  I'm wondering whats the easiest way to do this using a single event handler to monitor all, rather than writing 15 event handlers.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The requirement has to be checkboxes, i achieved it with the following:

```
$(".MESurfaceMountRow :checkbox").change(function (e) {

var idOfCheckbox = e.target.id;
idOfCheckbox = idOfCheckbox.replace(/\D/g, '');
var flushCheckBoxID = "#MEFlushMount" + idOfCheckbox;

if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
   $(flushCheckBoxID).prop('checked', false);
}

});

$(".MEFlushMountRow :checkbox").change(function (e) {

var idOfCheckbox = e.target.id;
idOfCheckbox = idOfCheckbox.replace(/\D/g, '');
var surfaceCheckBoxID = "#MESurfaceMount" + idOfCheckbox;

if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(surfaceCheckBoxID).prop('checked', false);
}

});
```

Comment: If you mean that for each column the user can chose only one of those options (either 'flush' or 'surface') then you should use radio buttons; they have this behaviour built in

Comment: please share script to toggle bewteen 'MESurfaceMount1' and 'MEFlushMount1' using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that for each column the user can chose only one of those options (either 'flush' or 'surface') then you should use radio buttons; they have this behaviour built in:

```html
<table>
    <tr class="MESurfaceMountRow">
        <td>Surface Mount</td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMount1" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMount2" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMount3" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMount4" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMount5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="MEFlushMountRow">
        <td>Flush Mount</td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMount1" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMount2" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMount3" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMount4" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMount5" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can guess from your question is that you want to select only one of flush of surface mount from each column. It can be best achieved with radio buttons. Radio buttons with a same name belong to same group and you can select only one out of them. I suppose this helps.

```html
<tr class="MESurfaceMountRow">
             <td>Surface Mount</td>
             <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMountRow1" id="MESurfaceMount1"></td>
             <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMountRow2" id="MESurfaceMount2"></td>
             <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMountRow3" id="MESurfaceMount3"></td>
             <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMountRow4" id="MESurfaceMount4"></td>
             <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMountRow5" id="MESurfaceMount5"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="MEFlushMountRow">
              <td>Flush Mount</td>
              <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMountRow1" id="MEFlushMount1"></td>
              <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMountRow2" id="MEFlushMount2"></td>
              <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMountRow3" id="MEFlushMount3"></td>
              <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMountRow4" id="MEFlushMount4"></td>
              <td><input type="radio" value="" name="MEMountRow5" id="MEFlushMount5"></td>
         </tr>
```